# How to with switching between jPanels in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am making a pong game with my game running in a jpanel window to the left. I added another jpanel window on the right so the user could reset the game and decide how how many points are needed for a win.

Anyway, when I interact with the buttons on the left panel(non game panel) I can't choose my game screen again and my game stops responding. I'm using netbeans and I'm a beginner so any help is appreciated!

Here is a picture of the problem, then game is controled with the keyboard. It keeps running but no longer responds to the keyboard when I press the button.
[image]
I also added some of my code.

```
public class LeikGluggi extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    int HRADISPADA = 10;
    Spilari1 spilari1;
    Spilari2 spilari2;
    Bolti bolti;
    public static int stadaLeiks = 0; //0 = stop, 1 = pása, 2 = spila


    public LeikGluggi() {
        initComponents();

        spilari1 = new Spilari1();
        spilari2 = new Spilari2();
        bolti = new Bolti();
        setSize(Leikbord.GLUGGI_BREIDD,Leikbord.GLUGGI_HAED);
        this.addKeyListener(this); //látum vita þegar ýtt er á takka
        this.setFocusable(true); //virkar bara þegar glugginn er valinn
        Timer klukka = new Timer(30, this);
        klukka.start();

    }
```

-

```
private void uppfaera()
{
    spilari1.uppfaera();
    spilari2.uppfaera();
    bolti.uppfaera();
    bolti.markCheck();
    bolti.skoppCheck(spilari1, spilari2);


}

public void resetLeik()
{

}


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{


    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    spilari1.paint(g);
    spilari2.paint(g);
    bolti.paint(g);         //bolti teiknaður

    if(stadaLeiks == 0)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString("Ýttu á bilstöng til að byrja", 50, 200);
    }
    if(stadaLeiks == 1)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 80));
        g.drawString("PÁSA", 210, 250);
    }


}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //þegar timer tikkar þá actinPerformed keyrt
    if(stadaLeiks == 2)
    {
        uppfaera();
    }                
    repaint(); 

}

//Spaði hreyfður ef ýtt er á takka 
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{   
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_P)
    {
        if (stadaLeiks != 2)
            stadaLeiks = 2;

        else stadaLeiks = 1;
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W)
    {
        spilari1.setyHradi(-HRADISPADA);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        spilari2.setyHradi(-HRADISPADA);  
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        spilari1.setyHradi(HRADISPADA);
    }

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
    {
        spilari2.setyHradi(HRADISPADA);  
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        spilari1.setyHradi(0);
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        spilari2.setyHradi(0);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add some of the code?

Comment: Please create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added some of the code and included a screenshot as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create new thread where you animate your object and let it sleep for a while , maybe you are blocking too much ui thread and your application just stops responding , Make sure that any action that updates your ui is handled on [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

From that thread change positions of your objects and use [InvokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))

I only adress not responding issue here , i dont see your code for a jbutton.
Note- edit your answer , i cant really see what you are asking here , and please try to use english language in a code sample at ,least some comments.